# C - Why is this program insecure?

Tags: c, memory, operating-system

I have homework in which I am supposed to analyze this C program and answer three questions. This is the program:

```
int main()
{
    // Define buffers to store username and password
    char username[16];
    char password[16];
    // Read username and password from user input
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", username);
    printf("Enter your password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);
    printf("[SHOUTING OUT LOUD] Hello, %s!\n", username);
    return 0;
}
```

These are the questions:

1. There is a security hole which makes it possible that the password will be printed. How is this possible?
2. How can it be achieved that the program crashes?
3. Correct the program so that there are no security holes anymore.

I think that the problem lies in the scanf method because the amount of characters which can be scanned is not limited. So I think by inputting a long string it is possible to get a segmentation fault because you want to save the characters in memory which must not be referenced by the user. This would be my answer for 2. The answer for 3 is that the program can be corrected by limiting the number of characters which can be scanned. But I don't seem to find an answer for 1. Could you help me out with this one?

Comment: What happens when user enters a string longer than 15 chars?

Comment: Another hint: if you enter a user name or password longer than 15 characters, you do not necessarily get a segmentation fault. Think about what cases that such a fault would not occur (*i.e.*, you are overrunning a buffer but still accessing your own memory).

Comment: Btw it is possible to gain full control over this program using this buffer overflow.

Comment: You would probably need to show how you handle (3); there are various ways to do it.

Comment: And honestly, code like this still happens on occasion which is why C for this type of work is dangerous...  This type of code can compromise entire systems depending on the existence or not of other OS level safe guards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine if the implementation stores the username and password consecutively in memory. It's vital that the print statement stop before it outputs the password. But it will only do this if it encounters a zero byte inside the username field. If the username is too long, there will be no zero byte in the username field, so the print could continue outputting the contents of the password field.

Comment: The `scanf` would overwrite the password until it writes a `\0`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @dan1st It will overwrite whatever of the username spilled into there with the password followed by a zero byte. So the print statement will output the first sixteen characters of the username followed by the password, stopping at that zero that the last `scanf` wrote.

Comment: But the `printf` would not print the password, everything before it would get overwritten and everything after it will not be printed because of the `\0`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The input of the username would not put a zero in the username field. The input of the password would put the password in the password field. Then the print would not stop until it printed everything in the password field because there's no zero before there and that's the only thing that can stop it.

Comment: I just forgot that the password is entered after the username

Answer (score 4):

Your `scanf` calls do *not* limit the number of bytes the user may enter.

A carefully crafted input could allow arbitrary execution of code because the string could overwrite the return address on the stack, inject arbitrary code, etc.

The injected code could examine the stack frame *memory* left over after the `return` and print the password.

The password stays in memory at the address on the stack assigned during the [legit] call to `main` for the `password` variable. After `main` returns, the password value is still there in the memory (i.e. it's not cleared)

This requires that the injected code *not* do stack operations that change the left over memory. Difficult, but not impossible.

To fix, try (e.g.):

```
scanf("%15s",username);
```

---

Another thing to consider is that, normally, information input via `scanf` is echoed by the TTY driver.

This is what we'd want for getting `username`. But, we'd want to disable echo in the TTY layer before the `scanf` for `password`.

We'd need to do something like `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` to effect this.

But, if we do that, it's tricky to get this to work with `scanf`. So, we should switch to pure `read(0,buf,1)` calls (e.g.)

Comment: "%99s" is bit much for a 15-character username...